# first order language of "sets"

Tags: logic

There is a list of variables symbols in the first order language (with "$=$") for sets

There is a list of logical operator symbols

There is a list of grouping symbols

There is a binary predicate symbol

No list of function symbols

No list of individual constant symbols (i.e names for sets)

Why is there no **list of names** (i.e., names for sets---objects of the Universe of Discourse) in the first order language of sets?

consider the following English language sentence

```
              some (unspecified) set is an element of a
```

where "$a$" is suppose to a "named" set (at least I think so---this is where my confusion is)

How would the above English sentence translate into the set-theoretic language if there's no names for sets? With variables I can always write
$$x\ \in\ x,\quad x\ \in\ y,\quad  y\ \in\ x,\quad y\ \in\ y$$with or without subscripts (using of course, the formal variable symbols of course---$x,\ \ y,\ z,$).  But about instantiating a formula like
$$x\ \in\ y$$Am I asking a silly question here or what?  Can someone "enlighten" me on this please.

Comment: Your question is not clear to me.

Comment: By "names for sets", do you mean symbols that can be used to name sets? If so, this is exactly what variables are for. Or do you mean that every set should come with a fixed name? If so, you should start by coming up with a list of names for every subset of the real numbers. You'll soon see where the trouble is...

Comment: Your English sentence can be expressed in the language of set theory as $\exists x\,x\in a$, where $a$ is a *variable*.

Comment: We do have names for sets... we call them defined terms. If we have that ∀x∃!yφ(x,y) for some formula φ in the language of set theory we define $F_φ(x)$ = y... A standard example is Ø = $F_φ(x)$ = y, where φ(x,y) = x$\in$y $\iff$  x$\neq$x

Comment: Formally, defined terms aren't part of the language, but anywhere they appear in a proof we can replace them by a formula which is in formal language

Answer (score 1):

Of course we can and do conservatively add names to the minimal first-order language of set theory. If there is one only one set which satisfies $\phi$, we can introduce a name for that set.

We do for this for the empty set, for example. We prove (or assume) that there is one and only one set with no members, and for convenience can add a name for it, $\emptyset$.

Later, for a more interesting case, we prove e.g. that there is a set whose members are exactly the finite von Neumann ordinals, and for convenience can add a name for it, $\omega$.

Why don't be build the name $\omega$ into the language from the start? Well, what would it denote? The set whose members are the finite von Neumann ordinals?? But how do we know when initially setting up the language that there is such a set??? That is something we surely want first to prove from our basic set theoretic assumptions. So that is the proper way of proceeding: first give our theory in the sparse language without a name for the set of finite von Neumann ordinals; then show there is a unique such set; and now we *can* add for convenience add a name for it. And then we *can* write the likes of $x \in \omega$ .

Comment: Hello Peter. Thank you for that explanation.  I thought there needed to be a list of symbols for constants in setting up the language.  But now what I am understanding is that names for individuals can be "added" after we have shown that the individuals  exists ---via a proof of course.  Am I now correct in this?

Comment: Yes. This is a standard procedure when working with first-order theories. See for example the section "Definitions of New Function Letters and Individual Constants" in Mendelson's classic *Introduction to Mathematical Logic*. There will be similar sections in other texts on FOL.